# Getting data from sharepoint permissions problem

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of sites, or a list of drives on a given sharepoint site.  the app that is registered has the below permissions.  I have confirmed that I am using the associated clientid,secret,appid to get my token.

[image]

When i make my call:

```
$myUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/someDriveId/items/root/children";
```

I get:

```
    [error] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => accessDenied
        [message] => Access denied
        [innerError] => stdClass Object
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @bart2puck Can you please decode your token and check if the above permissions are available in it here https://jwt.io/

if you are trying to list the children of the drive, these are the permissions required for it:

[image]

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-list-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions